# Android, can't integrate Dagger2 bacause of error “Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor ”

Tags: android, dagger-2

I want to integrate Dagger2, but i cant' build my project, build failed with:

```
error: com.example.animalslibrary.ui.home.activity.HomeActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
com.example.animalslibrary.ui.home.activity.HomeActivity is injected at
com.example.animalslibrary.AppComponent.injectsHomeActivity(homeActivity)
```

I looking for answer about 3 hours, and i asking you for help now.

My actions step by step:

1) Add depenceses to Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
```

2) Create empty test class `NetworkUtils`:

```
public class NetworksUtils {
}
```

3) Create module for it:

```
@Module
public class NetworksModule {
    @Provides
    NetworksUtils provideNetworksUtils() {
        return new NetworksUtils();
    }
}
```

4) Create "connection" interface:

```
import dagger.Component;

@Component(modules = NetworksModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void injectsHomeActivity(HomeActivity homeActivity);
}
```

5) Create `App` class. I don't completle understand why i did this(teaching by guide),exactly i don't understand why i need to extend  by `Application`. Maybe to create all components when application starts. `DaggerAppComponent` is red, because of failed while building, this class does't created yet.

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = DaggerAppComponent.create();
    }

    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

6) Add `App` to manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name="com.example.animalslibrary.ui.App"
        ...
```

7) Now i write my `HomeActivity` class...

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
HomeContract.View {
...
@Inject
private NetwotkUtils netwotkUtils;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ...
    App.getComponent().injectsHomeActivity(this);
    ...
    }
```

8)...and goes down when try to build project.

I think my error about `App`, but i can't understand where and how fix it.

**UPD:**

This modification is not helped:

```
public class NetwotkUtils {
    @Inject
    public NetwotkUtils() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Dagger (any version) is not injecting into private fields.

Comment: You use the Application class as a convenience.  You want only one version of the component across all activities (generally, there are exceptions).  It needs to be accessible to them all.  The easiest way to do that is to stick them in the Application, which is created first.

Comment: Also-  you're using a REALLY old version of Dagger.  Newer versions have tools to make things like Activity injection more convenient.  The newest version is 2.21

Comment: Gabe Sechan, ok, i understand about `App`, ty. It seems like singletons, which created first when app started. But i don't understend: how version 2.21 can be older that 2.7 i used? I watched Dagger2 `Github`, 2.21 there, it's rly last, so how i used 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code and one is leading to error you're getting.

1. You must include your module into building here `component = DaggerAppComponent.create();`
2. Dagger is NOT injecting into private fields.

Example of p1:

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder()
   .networkModule(new NetworkModule())
   .build()
```